# Volume level control component?

Tags: audio, components

does anybody know a component that can lower high volumes, but not the low ones, so the audio gets more equal?
A component that can make audio more constant. Limit audio.
[image]

Comment: The thing you're asking for has a name: It's a "[Dynamic Range Compressor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression)", or if you're an audio engineer, you might just call it a "compressor."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several companies make operational transconductance amplifiers (OTA) that can function as a voltage-controlled amplifier (VCA).  National/TI LM13600, LM13700 and the RCA/Harris/Intersil CA3080 parts come to mind.  A company called Solid State Music was big in this.  They got bought up by Analog Devices.  ADI kept some of the old SSM part numbers.

Also, THAT Corp. for very high signal quality.  The basic idea is a non-linear compressor that limits peak signal levels without hard clipping, while not affecting lower signal levels.

http://thatcorp.com/Analog_Engine_Dynamics_Processor_ICs.shtml

A less complicated option is to modify a standard non-inverting or inverting opamp gain stage with two additional diodes and one resistor in the series feedback path.  This creates a feedback impedance that is dependent on the instantaneous value of the signal voltage, reducing the gain of the stage if the signal is high enough for the diodes to conduct.  This will "round off" the signal peaks with very little effect on the lower signal levels.  Here is an example of an inline peak limiter.

https://www.electroschematics.com/dynamic-compressor-passive-components-no-power-supply/